# Is it unacceptable to start the second clause of a semicolon with a number?

Tags: orthography, numbers, semicolons, style-manuals

I know it's generally frowned upon to start a sentence with a number encoded by Arabic numerals, e.g. "4 percent of people live in the USA". Is it okay to do this for the second clause connected by a semicolon?

For example, "Wealth is often unevenly distributed; 4 percent of the world lives in the USA, but it makes up a much larger part of the global economy." For some reason, this doesn't feel as wrong as the first example I gave.

Do any style guides have any recommendations about this?

Comment: I'd say the rather silly restriction on not starting a sentence with a number has itself been considerably relaxed nowadays. Most style guides recommend that counting numbers 1 - 9 are spelled out, though.

Comment: What does this have to do about ***grammar*** or ***grammaticality***? The choice of writing *4* versus *four* is no more about grammar than writing *Ⅳ* for  *four* would be.  Or for *for* for that matter. :)

Comment: @tchrist — “Ask about... Spelling and punctuation” is [right there in the site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), and this question qualifies on both counts.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I didn't mean to somehow imply that it was a wrong question, just a wrong tag. It was tagged [tag:grammaticality] when it should have instead been tagged [tag:orthography] and perhaps [tag:style-manuals]. Spelling and punctuation are certainly fine things to ask about here. But we should not pretend that their possible variations represent grammatical errors, only orthographic errors—at most. I've just edited the tags on the question, so by and by I'll delete these comments once they've likely been read.

Comment: I would use: 4%, not write it out, especially in an article that may cite various percentages and it has nothing to do with it being an independent clause or not.

Answer (score 2):

According to *The Chicago Manual of Style*, yes, an independent clause following a semicolon can begin with a numeral . . .

> When a number begins a sentence, it is always spelled out.
> <sub>Source: [*The Chicago Manual of Style* — 9.5: Number beginning a
> sentence](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch09/psec005.html)
> (login required)</sub>

This is because . . .

> . . . a numeral isn’t as effective as a capital letter
> at signaling the start of a new sentence.
>  <sub>Source: [*CMOS*
> Style Q&A —
> Numbers](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Numbers.html?page=1)</sub>

But both independent clauses in the semicolon structure comprise one sentence. . .

> . . . a semicolon is most commonly used between two
> independent clauses not joined by a conjunction to signal a closer
> connection between them than a period would.
>   <sub>Source: [[*The
> Chicago Manual of Style* —  6.56: Use of the semicolon](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch06/psec056.html)</sub>

Finally, addressing percentages, *CMOS* offers this example:

> *Thirty-nine percent identified the “big bang” as the origin of the universe; 48 percent said they believed in human evolution.*
> <sub>Source: [*The Chicago Manual of Style* —  9.18:
> Percentages](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch09/psec018.html)
> (login required)</sub>

(Note that there are always rules waiting to be broken and other style guides waiting to be followed.)

Comment: Though earlier one could imagine that OP's case hadn't been considered by the authors, the final example you cite is indisputably what they recommend. +1 for finding it. // Personally, I find 'Thirty-nine percent ... 48 percent ...' a comical mismatch. And I'd say a numeral is probably considered a little uncouth by traditionalists, rather than it being inadequate to signal the start of a sentence. They stand out in most sentences.

Comment: I agree it’s a comical mismatch. To its credit though, *CMOS* is the first to say “reword”: *To avoid awkwardness, a sentence can often be recast... it is usually preferable, however, to reword...* etc.

Comment: Yes. 'I was able 'ere I saw Elba' isn't an improvement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Awkwardness reigns supreme in service of a palindrome.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — And the passive voice is always eager to help...  *The “big bang” was identified as the origin of the universe by 39 percent; 48 percent said...*

Comment: I'd just ignore CMOS here.